# PageObject/Cucumber String being input incorrectly

Tags: ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

In my scenario outline I have the below

```
Examples:
    | user   | password | from            | to            | amount | date      | message           |
    | joel10 | lolpw12  | bankA           | bankB         | $100   | 1/30/2015 | Transfer Success. |
```

in my step definitions I have the below

```
And(/^the user inputs fields (.*), (.*), (.*)$/) do |from, to, amount|
  on(TransferPage).from = /#{from}/
  on(TransferPage).to = /#{to}/
  on(TransferPage).amount = /#{amount}/
  on(TransferPage).date = /#{date}/
end
```

The FROM, TO, and AMOUNT all comes out correct from the table but when it inputs the date, it comes out (?-mix:1/30/2015)

why is this happening and how do i fix?

Comment: Can you add the code of the step definitions : it will help

Comment: the above is the step definition in question, I dont have much besides that.   It's just putting in data from the table into the input fields.

Comment: I am surprised that you do not have this problem with the other inputs as they are also being turned into Regexps. Where is `date` actually coming from? It's not coming from your step definition name since it only collect from, to and amount.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `/#{date}/` you are taking the value returned from the parsing of the step definition and then turning it into a regular expression:

```
/#{date}/.class
#=> Regexp
```

You presumably want to leave the value in its original String format:

```
on(TransferPage).date = date
```

Comment: yup on(TransferPage).date = date worked! Really appreciate your help :)